# Can I override page buddy's recommended applications settings?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, app-widgets, headphones

When I plug in my headphones, an Earphones page appears on my device with the title "Enjoy listening to your device", which is part of page buddy. I have a music widget and a video widget, which is fine.

My first two applications are fine, Firefox and YouTube, *but my last two applications are Messaging and Email*. Apparently it's supposed to be frequency of use, but I never use the Email app, and neither the Messaging app nor the Email app are aural.

When I try to change these two apps, it says "Cannot edit recommended apps". Can I fix this to stop displaying non-aural apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the most frequently used apps while the earphones are plugged in. just open the app you want to show up 4 or 5 times in a row while the page buddy is active (earphones plugged in) and it will show up in the recommended apps. repeat for the next 3 apps you want to show. There's usually 4 recommended apps. This goes for all of the page buddy pages, earphones, docking, roaming, and spen (on supported devices).

Comment: Wow, that is terrible development.